# How do I define svg attributes in virtual-dom?

Tags: javascript, svg, virtual-dom

Is there a way to add svg attributes to nodes using virtual-hyperscript in virtual dom? For example, something like this:

```
var h = require('virtual-dom/h')

h('svg', [
    h('circle', {cx: 100, cy: 100}, 'some text')
])
```

I've tried to do this myself, but the attributes are removed on `create`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you do this:

```
h('circle', {namespace: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", attributes: {cx: 100}})
```

- Need the attributes key
- Need the namespace - this is because the browser treats `createElement` and `createElementNS` as two different things even though they output the same html. Namespace is needed to differentiate it from a normal DOM element.

See: https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom/tree/master/virtual-hyperscript#namespace